# Every finite metric space is discrete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I know that the question is so easy, but I don't know how to conclude. I have that:

Let $X$ be a finite metric space. Suppose that $X$ isn't discrete, then exists $x\in X$ such that, $\forall \epsilon >0$, $(B(x,\epsilon)-\lbrace x \rbrace) \cap X \ne \emptyset $, then with this I can say that $X$ isn't finite, but how can I conclude?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

It's probably easier to prove it directly.

**Hint:**  Consider $\varepsilon = \min \{ d (x,y) : x \neq y \in X \}$.